# Timer with a trigger at every 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, performance, datetime, optimization

I needed a highly reliable timer/clock that monitors the time, and triggers at every 5 minutes (actually 5min -1sec, e.g. xx:59), precisely. It needed to be asynchronous because the trigger at the 5min mark will call a function or functions that will perform a task in the background.

So... I came up with this super simple routine. I'm looking for feedback. Should I be doing anything different? Is this a reliable enough solution to use in production? recommendations and criticisms are welcome. Good, bad, or indifferent!

**EDITED: Forgot this line of code:
`minutes = ( mminutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + mminutes;`

```
          var minuteData,hours,minutes,seconds;

          setInterval(function() {
            var date = new Date;
            hours = date.getHours();
            mminutes = date.getMinutes();
            seconds = date.getSeconds();
            minutes = ( mminutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + mminutes;
            //get the second digit of minutes
            minuteData = minutes.toString()[1];
            console.log(minuteData);
            //test if at time x4:59 or x9:59, hence 1 sec before the 5min interval
            var trigger = ((seconds == 59 && (minuteData == "9" || minuteData == "4")) ? true : false);
            console.log(trigger);
            //trigger is just a proxy for a task that will be called

          }, 1000);
```

Comment: this wont be "precise" ... it could trigger at x:x[49]:59.0 or x:x[49]:59.999 - almost a second difference

Comment: you'll find this is highly inaccurate if the page loses focus. I thought requestAnimationFrame may help, but it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I would probably define the function as a named function and then on the setInterval - call the function. Probably the same performance, but allows you to call it on page load, or on specific actions etc.

```
function testTime(){
          var minuteData,hours,minutes,seconds;
            var date = new Date;
            hours = date.getHours();
            minutes = date.getMinutes();
            seconds = date.getSeconds();
            //get the second digit of minutes
            minuteData = minutes.toString()[1];
            console.log(minuteData);
            //test if at time x4:59 or x9:59, hence 1 sec before the 5min interval
            var trigger = ((seconds == 59 && (minuteData == "9" || minuteData == "4")) ? true : false);
            console.log(trigger);
}


 setInterval(function() {testTime()}, 1000);
```

Comment: Can also use local storage to store the time in case of loss of focus as in comments also you might need to go down to milliseconds for accuracy